# Low Search with LOW_options mix channel field with category

Tags: low-search, low

I do not know how to put it, there seem to be confusion.

```
    <div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-4 large-up-6" >
  {exp:low_options:material_content}
    {options}
        <div class="column"><input id="{option:label}" type="checkbox" name="search:material_content[]" value="{option:value}"
        {if low_search_search:material_content ~ '/(^|\|)'.option:value.'(\||$)/'} checked{/if}><label for="checkbox1">{option:label}</label></div>
      </label>
    {/options}
  {/exp:low_options:material_content}
  <button type="submit">sök material</button>
  </div>
```

show, in my form, checkboxes corresponding to field content (as expected) but **also content from a category group!**. As checkbox, yes.
The form does not give any result either.

I can provide screenshots but do not know how to attach them to this question.

Any help highly appreciated, because itäs just confusion here.. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you try and elaborate? Also, can you share your full template? There might be some tag conflicts in place here.

Comment: Hi, I must apologize here. My bad. I've used the same fieldgroup for another channel (changes my mind, named Categories exact as content of those entrees and forgot bout it, some time ago, never used) and the results showed as tick boxes thanks to your plugin. If you want to make your reaction as answer (confict) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credits must go to Low, he suggested out that there might be a conflict that caused the problem. And there was. A name conflict between a category name and a fieldname.